# boost::allocate_unique yields non-deafult constructible and non-move assignable unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, allocator

I have a question about `allocate_unique` from Boost. It looks like that resulting `unique_ptr`s are quite limited - they cannot be default constructed to `nullptr` without providing a deleter (even an invalid one), and also, move assignment does not work.

Luckily, move construction does work, so I was able to hack around not having move assignment by calling the destructor and move-constructing using placement new.

Is it a defect in Boost that `alloc_deleter` is not moveable, and thus disables move assignment of these `unique_ptr`s? Or am I misunderstanding something?

```
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/allocate_unique.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Pma = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
template<typename T> using pmr_deleter = boost::alloc_deleter<T, Pma>;
template<typename T> using pmr_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>;
  
struct Vertex {
    float x = 1;
    float y = 2;
    float z = 3;
};

int main() {
    auto& res = *std::pmr::new_delete_resource();
    pmr_deleter<Vertex> d(nullptr);
    pmr_unique_ptr<Vertex> v_empty(nullptr, d); // will not default construct without deleter??
    pmr_unique_ptr<Vertex> v = boost::allocate_unique<Vertex>(Pma(&res), Vertex{7,8,9});

    // v_empty = std::move(v); // operator=(unique_ptr&&) gets deleted because `alloc_deleter` is not moveable!

    // We can hack in a move like this:
    v_empty.~pmr_unique_ptr<Vertex>();
    new (&v_empty) pmr_unique_ptr<Vertex>(v.get(), v.get_deleter());
    v.release();

    std::cout << v_empty->x << "," << v_empty->y << "," << v_empty->z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphic allocators are stateful, which means they cannot be default-constructed - because they wouldn't know about the memory resource they're supposed to work with.

This is not particular to PMR or unique pointers, it will also crop up when e.g. using Boost Interprocess allocators on a `vector` - you will always have to pass an initializer for the allocator.

Ifff you want a global/singleton memory resource, you can obviously declare a custom deleter that encodes that constant:

```
template <typename T> struct pmr_deleter : boost::alloc_deleter<T, Pma> {
    pmr_deleter()
            : boost::alloc_deleter<T, Pma>(std::pmr::new_delete_resource()) {}
};
```

This would allow the default constructor(s) to work:

```
pmr_unique_ptr<Vertex> v_empty; // FINE
pmr_unique_ptr<Vertex> v_empty(nullptr); // ALSO FINE
```

However it comes at the cost of no longer being type-compatible with the `allocate_unique` factory return type (`alloc_deleter`).

> You *can* probably pave hack this, but I think it would probably be best to understand the situation before you decide whether that's worth it. (*Hint: I don't think it is, because it is precisely the goal of PMR to type erase the allocator difference, trading in runtime state instead. If you go and move all state into the allocator again, you effectively made it a static allocator again, which is where we would have been without PMR anyways*)

### Other Notes

```
pmr_deleter<Vertex> d(nullptr);
```

Is ill-formed, as the argument may never be null. Both the compiler will [warn about this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wnonnull) at `-Wnon-null`, just as Asan/UBSan will:

```
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:18:34: runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 2, which is declared to never be null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Passing a default for the allocator isn't a big problem, that's just a couple of characters more (for example, when I want to initialize an empty unique_ptr, I could pass in the null resource).

Lack of operator=(unique_ptr&&) is a lot more annoying, though. Do you have comments about this?

Comment: Yeah. It's tough bind. I suppose you could make a wrapper that basically asserts that the allocators of the `alloc_deleter<>` instances match. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I have a feeling this is mostly a problem with `alloc_deleter` not being aware of stateful allocators, not `unique_ptr` per se, so it might be more natural to come up with your own combo of `allocate_unique`/`unique_alloc_deleter` implementations that doesn't have that limitation. I can't, off the top of my head, think of reasons that couldn't work. For the same reason the Boost devs might be interested in a feature request.

Comment: Hmm, but with shared pointers (which have the allocator i.e. the deleter fully type-erased), you can redirect the smart pointer from one object with one allocator (deleter) to another with a different allocator (deleter) of possibly completely different type. Unique pointers don't have the deleter erased, but why would you limit them to the same allocator/deleter instance? The difference should only be in that they have unique ownership over the object. They should be able to switch from managing an object associated with one allocator instance to one managed by a different allocator instance.

Comment: @JurajOršulić I wouldn't want to limit, I was just observing that `boost::alloc_deleter<>` deosn't **support** (move) re-assignment, hence asserting equivalence is the only thing you can hope to do.

Comment: I was told on Boost IRC that the reason `alloc_deleter` does not support move assignment is because the contained allocator (in this case `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`) itself does not support (move) assignment at all, since you are not supposed to change an object's PMR allocator once you construct it. This is completely reasonable, but it ends up killing the move assignment operator for the unique pointer. For now, I have wrapped my destruct-then-call placement new thing into an operator-like function (`MoveAssignPmrUniquePtr(pmr_unique_ptr<T>& left, pmr_unique_ptr<T>&& right)`). Thanks!

Comment: The resttriction "should not change an object's PMR allocator once you construct[ed] it" makes sense in a lot of siutations (where the allocator reflects [contained] object identity). However, in this case you are clearly looking at a valid use case to move them around, _with_ that corresponding object.

Comment: As a corollary, you could cheat and put the allocator inside the element type - which is restoing that assumption (that the allocator stays with its object). Going the other way I suppose you could be really ugly and make a shared allocator [this violates the principle that allocators should be cheap to pass by value]

Comment: Off topic: if you want to know what really grinds my gears: PMR is an elegant building block that puts stateful allocator support into the standard library, but they missed the mark where it **does not** support fancy pointer types. This means that for more advanced applications (shared memory with offset-pointers e.g.) we're still stuck in incompatible static allocator type hell. - See https://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/fancy-pointers.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wrapper I wrote around the specialization of `std::unique_ptr<T, boost::alloc_deleter>`. The unique pointer returned by `boost::allocate_unique` is implicitly convertible to the wrapper. The wrapper is default constructible, move-assignable and also has `.get()` return a raw pointer instead of a boost fancy pointer type (which requires an additional `.ptr()` to get a raw pointer).

The only downside is that you have to use the wrapper explicitly instead of e.g. `auto` with `boost::allocate_unique`.

```
using Pma = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
template<typename T> using pmr_deleter = boost::alloc_deleter<T, Pma>;
template<typename T> class pmr_unique_ptr : public std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>> {
  public:
    using std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>::unique_ptr;
    T* get() const { return std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>::get().ptr(); }
    pmr_unique_ptr() : std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>(nullptr, pmr_deleter<T>(std::pmr::null_memory_resource())) { }
    pmr_unique_ptr(decltype(nullptr)) : pmr_unique_ptr() { }
    template<typename P>
    pmr_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<P, pmr_deleter<P>>&& p)
        : pmr_unique_ptr(static_cast<T*>(p.get().ptr()), *reinterpret_cast<pmr_deleter<T>*>(&p.get_deleter())) {
        p.release();
    }
    template<>
    pmr_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>&& p) : std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>(std::move(p)) { };
    pmr_unique_ptr(T* p, pmr_deleter<T> d) :  std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>(boost::detail::sp_alloc_ptr<T,T *>(1, p), d) { };
    pmr_unique_ptr(const pmr_unique_ptr&) = delete;
    pmr_unique_ptr(pmr_unique_ptr&& p) : std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>(std::move(p)) { }
    template<typename P> operator pmr_unique_ptr<P>() {
        P* basep = static_cast<P*>(get());
        pmr_deleter<P> d(*reinterpret_cast<pmr_deleter<P>*>(&this->get_deleter()));
        this->release();
        return {basep, std::move(d)};
    }
    pmr_unique_ptr& operator=(pmr_unique_ptr&& other) {
        this->std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>::~unique_ptr();
        new (static_cast<std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>*>(this)) std::unique_ptr<T, pmr_deleter<T>>(std::move(other));
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename P> pmr_unique_ptr& operator=(std::unique_ptr<P, pmr_deleter<P>>&& p) {
        return operator=(pmr_unique_ptr(pmr_unique_ptr<P>(std::move(p))));
    }
};
```

Example which compiles:

```
#include <memory_resource>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/allocate_unique.hpp>

// ... the definitions from above
// ...

  pmr_unique_ptr<int> p;
  pmr_unique_ptr<int> p2 = nullptr;

  p2 = boost::allocate_unique<int>(Pma(std::pmr::new_delete_resource()), 5);
  p = std::move(p2);
  int *rawp = p.get();
```